# TikZ: edge should not interfere with other elements in the graph and label positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm quite new to TikZ and I created the following graph:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw,circle] (n4) at (2, -3) {4};
\node[draw,circle] (n5) at (2, -4) {5};
\node[draw,circle] (n6) at (1, -5) {6};
\node[draw,circle] (n7) at (3, -5) {7};
\node[draw,circle] (n8) at (1, -6) {8};
\node[draw,circle] (n9) at (3, -6) {9};
\node[draw,circle] (n10) at (2, -7) {10};

\draw[->] (n4)--(n5) node[midway, right] {lengthy edge label 1};
\draw[->] (n5)--(n6) node[midway, left] {lengthy edge label 2};
\draw[->] (n5)--(n7) node[midway, right] {lengthy edge label 3};
\draw[->] (n6)--(n8) node[midway, left] {edge label 4};
\draw[->] (n7)--(n9) node[midway, right] {edge label 5};
\draw[->] (n9)--(n10) node[midway, right] {label 6};
\draw[->] (n8)--(n10) node[midway, left] {label 7};

\draw[->] (n10) -| +(4,0) -- +(4,0) node[midway, right]  {edge label 8} |- (n4);    

\end{tikzpicture}
```

An image of the output can be found here:

[image]

It took me quite a while for this graph to build. However, I couldn't come up with a solution for the following questions:

- Is it possible to set the path of the edge from node 10 to node 4 in such a way that it automatically bypasses the rightmost "inner" label? In the example above I have to adjust the value in `\draw` to something like `+(5,0)` so that it doesn't interfere with "lengthy edge label 3", but this seems quite cumbersome if the graph changes frequently
- How can I place "edge label 8" in the middle of the vertical path segment?
- Is it possible to increase the distances between the nodes without having to assign new coordinate points to each node?

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @moeso, [welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! `:)`

Comment: Hi @Paulo, Thank you both for including the image and for welcoming me :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used another node `(c)` and I added sme styles.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=1.5cm]

\begin{scope} [every node/.style={draw,circle}]
    \node (n4) at (2, -3) {4};
    \node (n5) at (2, -4) {5};
    \node (n6) at (1, -5) {6};
    \node (n7) at (3, -5) {7};
    \node (n8) at (1, -6) {8};
    \node (n9) at (3, -6) {9};
    \node (n10)at (2, -7) {10}; 
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[->,every node/.style={ right}]
  \draw (n4)-- node{lengthy edge label 1} (n5);
  \draw (n5)-- node[left] {lengthy edge label 2}(n6)  ;
  \draw (n5)-- node (c) {lengthy edge label 3}(n7) ;
  \draw (n6)-- node[left] {edge label 4}(n8)  ;
  \draw (n7)-- node {edge label 5}(n9)  ;
  \draw (n9)-- node {label 6}(n10) ;
  \draw (n8)-- node[left] {label 7}(n10) ;
\end{scope}

\draw[->] (n10) -| (c.east) coordinate (d)  |-  (n4);
\node [right,anchor=west]  at (n7-|d) {edge label 8} ;   

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**update**

The problem with `positioning` is to scale the picture. A possibility is to use

```
\begin{scope} [every node/.style={draw,circle}]
    \path
          ( 2 ,-3)  node  (n4)  {4}
      ++  ( 0 ,-1)  node  (n5)  {5}
      ++  (-1 ,-1)  node  (n6)  {6}
      ++  ( 0 ,-1)  node  (n8)  {8}
      ++  ( 1 ,-1)  node  (n10) {10}
      ++  ( 1 , 1)  node  (n9)  {9}
      ++  ( 0 , 1)  node  (n7)  {7}; 
\end{scope}
```

and if you don't like the coordinates

```
 \def\dn{++( 0 ,-1)}   \def\up{++( 0 ,1)}
 \def\rdn{++( 1 ,-1)}  \def\rup{++( 1 ,1)} 
 \def\ldn{++( -1 ,-1)} \def\lup{++( -1 ,1)}  
\begin{scope} [every node/.style={draw,circle}]
    \path
          ( 2 ,-3)  node  (n4)  {4}
              \dn   node  (n5)  {5}
              \ldn  node  (n6)  {6}
              \dn   node  (n8)  {8}
              \rdn  node  (n10) {10}
              \rup  node  (n9)  {9}
              \up   node  (n7)  {7}; 
\end{scope}
```

Comment: I added `y=1.5cm` to get some vertical space

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Also `positioning` library is suitable for such tasks...

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=6mm and 5mm,] %You can individually assign x and y distances

\node[draw,circle] at (2, -3)         (n4) {4};
\node[draw,circle,below= of n4]       (n5) {5};
\node[draw,circle,below left= of n5]  (n6) {6};
\node[draw,circle,below right= of n5] (n7) {7};
\node[draw,circle,below= of n6]       (n8) {8};
\node[draw,circle,below= of n7]       (n9) {9};
\node[draw,circle,below left= of n9]  (n10) {10};

\draw[->] (n4)--(n5) node[midway, right] {lengthy edge label 1};
\draw[->] (n5)--(n6) node[midway, left] {lengthy edge label 2};
\draw[->] (n5)--(n7) node[midway, right] (l1) {lengthy edge label 3};
\draw[->] (n6)--(n8) node[midway, left] {edge label 4};
\draw[->] (n7)--(n9) node[midway, right] {edge label 5};
\draw[->] (n9)--(n10) node[midway, right] {label 6};
\draw[->] (n8)--(n10) node[midway, left] {label 7};

\draw[->] (n10) -| (l1.east)  node[midway,right]  {edge label 8} |- (n4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you too, @percusse. I really like the way of the relative positioning of the nodes instead of assigning coordinate points.

Comment: Why not simplify your code with styles and scopes?

Comment: @Altermundus I think you have covered that with your answer, this is just to complement yours.

Answer (score 6):

Since the point *How can I place "edge label 8" in the middle of the vertical path segment?* wasn't fixed so far, my answer tries to address it.

Your initial `midway` in this case does not holds thus you can made use of the manual `pos=`.

For example:

```
% Basic code taken from percusse's answer
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=6mm and 5mm]

\node[draw,circle] at (2, -3)         (n4) {4};
\node[draw,circle,below= of n4]       (n5) {5};
\node[draw,circle,below left= of n5]  (n6) {6};
\node[draw,circle,below right= of n5] (n7) {7};
\node[draw,circle,below= of n6]       (n8) {8};
\node[draw,circle,below= of n7]       (n9) {9};
\node[draw,circle,below left= of n9]  (n10) {10};

\draw[->] (n4)--(n5) node[midway, right] {lengthy edge label 1};
\draw[->] (n5)--(n6) node[midway, left] {lengthy edge label 2};
\draw[->] (n5)--(n7) node[midway, right] (l1) {lengthy edge label 3};
\draw[->] (n6)--(n8) node[midway, left] {edge label 4};
\draw[->] (n7)--(n9) node[midway, right] {edge label 5};
\draw[->] (n9)--(n10) node[midway, right] {label 6};
\draw[->] (n8)--(n10) node[midway, left] {label 7};

\draw[->] (n10) -| (l1.east)  node[pos=0.9,right]  {edge label 8} |- (n4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

will lead to:

[image]

Of course, the positioning thanks to `pos=0.9` also applies to the method shown by Altermundus in his answer.

Comment: I'm impressed - all my questions have been answered in a matter of minutes. Thank you too for your helpful contribution, @Claudio.

Comment: Why not simplify your code with styles and scopes?

Comment: @Altermundus: my answer actually just tries to address the edge positioning. I could have answered simply saying use `node[pos=0.9,right]`, but I thought was better show the complete example. I chose @percusse's answer making there my small change and I saw that he answered you on motivations.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: Nice! And if you use `\draw[->] (n10) -- (n10-|l1.east) |- (n4) node[pos=0.25,right] {edge label 8};` (i.e. draw a straight line to the bottom right corner first, and only one `|-` line), the label is actually centered vertically, and not just approximately.

Comment: @Jake: you are right. :) To be honest, this would never have come in my mind: many thanks. And you are right: I compared the two pictures with the two cases discovering that yours has really the perfect alignment (mine is slightly below).

Comment: Yes it's right; another possibility is `\draw[->] (n10) -| (c.east) coordinate (d)  |-  (n4);`
`\node [right,anchor=west]  at (n7-|d) {edge label 8} ;` and possible is   `\draw (n4)-- node{lengthy edge label 1} (n5);` to avoid `midway`